# REGEX to detect periods and capital letters are correctly separated by a space

Tags: php, regex

Consider this sentence:

> This sentence concerning LASER applications ends here.Naturally this
>   sentence should have started with a space. This one is fine.This one is not.

I am looking to use preg_replace to correctly separate the periods and capitals in the two places that are incorrect "here.Naturally" and "fine.This".

Everything else should remain untouched.

The closest I have got is `(?<!\ )[A-Z]` which I employed:

```
$this_desc = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $this_desc);
```

...but it also matches the first capital and the capitals in the acronym "LASER"... [regexr.com/3ss3o](http://regexr.com/3ss3o)

Comment: To be honest, without using a dictionary, it isn't possible to do that since this kind of pattern isn't able to deal with edge cases like acronyms separated by dots or abbreviations. Natural Language Processing (NLP) is more than a naive pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for search with look-arounds:

```
/(?<!\h)\.(?=[A-Z])/
```

or to make it recognize Unicode uppercase letters use:

```
/(?<!\h)\.(?=\p{Lu})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VODghC/1)

**Code:**

```
$this_desc = preg_replace('/(?<!\h)\.(?=[A-Z])/', '$0 ', $this_desc);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\h)`: Lookbehind to assert that we don't have a horizontal space at previous position
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `(?=[A-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we have a capital letter ahead

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. My brain and RegEx are sadly incompatible! :(